# Different occurrences of “que”, “qu'” or “qui” in questions

Tags: questions, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-interrogatifs

> Qui est-ce ___ parle ?

What should the blank be filled with?

- que
- qu'
- qui

I am really confused about this! Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Here are example of correct uses of "*qui*" and "*que*" :

> Qu'est-ce **que** tu en penses ? (**What** do you think ?)
>
> Qui est-ce **qui** parle ? (**Who**'s talking ?)

"*Qu'* " is the form of "*que*" used before a vowel, like in "***qu'**est-ce que ...*", or in "*qu'est ce **qu'** il en pense ?*"

Sometimes the first pronoun is the same as the second one (assuming "*qu'* " == "*que*"), but it's not always the case.

When it is, you can phrase these sentence to use only one pronoun, though it's a little too formal for casual conversation :

> **Qu'**en penses-tu ?
>
> **Qui** parle ?

---

Edit : As Stéphane mentioned, there are other cases, when this doesn't work :

> Qu'est-ce **qui** est rond et rouge ?

This phrasing is typical in riddles for example.

In the last sentence, we're  still talking about and object, but there's a difference : "*Qu'est-ce*" is the **subject**, to the verb "*être*" : "***Il*** *est rond est rouge*".

While in the first sentence, "*Qu'est-ce*" is the **complement**, while **tu** is the subject : "*Qu'est-ce que **tu** en penses ?*".

So here is the rule: **qui** follows the **subject** of the verb, while **que**/**qu'** follows the **complement**.

My apologies for my hasty and incorrect first answer.

Comment: “Qu'est-ce qui est rouge ?”

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hmm... je m'attendais à ce genre de choses donc j'ai cherché des contre-exemples mais j'en ai pas trouvé, merci. Je me doutais que c'était pas aussi simple. Je vais essayer d'affiner ma réponse (en quelque chose de correct)

Comment: J'ai corrigé les énormités de ma première réponse, et j'ai rajouté la vraie règle que j'ai fini par trouver (j'espère !).

Answer (score 1):

“Qui est-ce ?” when speaking to somebody and indicating someone means you want information on this someone.

“Qui est-ce qui parle ?” is the exact same question except that you indicate this someone by the fact that he is speaking right now.

Answer (score 1):

[FR: qu'est-ce qui / qu'est-ce que / qui est-ce qui / qui est-ce que | WordReference Forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-quest-ce-qui-quest-ce-que-qui-est-ce-qui-qui-est-ce-que.286335/#post-1732651)

> The first *que/qui* tells you whether the answer to your question will be a person (*qui*) or an thing (*que*).
> The second *que/qui* tells you whether the answer to your question will be the subject or the object.
>
> **QUI**
> SUJET: Qui est-ce qui mange? Il mange.
> OBJECT: Qui est-ce que vous aimez? J'aime James.
>
> **QUE**
> SUJET: Qu'est-ce qui te fait mal? Mon dos me fait mal.
> OBJET: Qu'est-ce que vous voulez? Je veux un chaton.

When you have *Qui...qui* or *Que...que*, you can omit the *est-ce* part:

Qui est-ce qui mange? → Qui mange?
Qu'est-ce que vous voulez? → Que voulez-vous?